# Erro ao salvar dados usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tendo um problema para inserir dados no banco utilizando o PDO e não sei o motivo, ao meu ver tudo parece estar certo, segue abaixo os codigos.

Classe modelo

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $nome;

    public setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public getNome(){
        return $this->nome; 
    }
}
```

Classe DAO

```
class UsuarioDao implements Dao {
    private $conexao;  

    function __construct(){
        $connection = new Connection();
        $this->conexao = $connection->getConnection();
    }    

    public function insert($user){ 
        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome) VALUES(:nome)";
            $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            $this->conexao->bindValue(':nome',$user->getNome(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            return $this->conexao->execute();    
        }catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Instancia das classes

```
require_once('User.class.php');
require_once('UserDao.class.php');

class Teste {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setNome('Gabriel');

    $userDao = new UserDao();
    $userDao->insert($user);         
}
```

Sobre o log do erro não aparece mensagem alguma, só a mensagem de erro 500.

E estou recebendo o erro 500 toda hora que executo esse código, gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a encontrar o erro nesse código.
Comecei a aprender PHP agora tenho mais conhecimento em JAVA aproveitando a pergunta vocês conhecem algum framework ORM tipo o Hibernate para PHP ?

Comment: A primeira coisa é ver o log de erros do PHP e/ou do servidor http para saber o problema. Qual o motivo de colocar a classe User, se você não mostra o instanciamento dela no código?

Comment: Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e colocar todas as partes relevantes, incluso o instanciamento. De qualquer forma, é praticamente certo que a resposta para o problema esteja no log de erros do servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver fiz a seguinte alteração :

```
    public function insert($user){ 
    try {
        $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome) VALUES(:nome)";
        $resultado = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
        $resultado->bindValue(':nome',$user->getNome(),PDO::PARAM_STR);

        return $resultado->execute();    
    }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Criei a variavel $resultado para receber a preparação da query e funcionou, obrigado aos colegas que tentaram me ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Troque

```
class Teste {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setNome('Gabriel');

    $userDao = new UserDao();
    $userDao->insert($user);         
}
```

por

```
class Teste {
    $user = new User();
    $nome = $user->setNome('Gabriel');

    $userDao = new UserDao();
    $userDao->insert($nome);         
}
```

veja se resolva, eu apenas introduzi uma variável, `$nome` para receber `$user->setNome('Gabriel');`